# Update AWS ELB listeners from command line tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-cli

Problem: update listeners in AWS ELB in transaction-like mode. I.e. delete-load-balancer-listeners followed by create-load-balancer-listeners isn't good.

AWS UI console allows you to **update** list of listeners (at least it looks like update), not just delete+add.

Is there a way to do that programmatically or from aws cli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudTrail logs shows that AWS UI console does delete+create. There's no undocumented "update listeners" API call.

Open questions left:

- What happens if delete succeed but create failed? ELB should just reject connections in this case. What's the best practices to avoid downtime here?
- What happens to existing connections?